# customize shorcut (right-click) menu powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to make appear a new element on the shortcut menu, known also as right-click menu. I want this element to execute a macro that I made. I check on the web but I could find a solution that really work. I put here which one I tried:

```
Public Sub customizeRightClick()
    Dim pic As IPictureDisp
    Set pic = LoadPicture("C:\path\pic.jpg")
    For Each oCmdBar In Application.CommandBars
        If oCmdBar.Type = msoBarTypePopup Then
            If oCmdBar.Name = "Shapes" Then
                Set cmdButton = oCmdBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                    With cmdButton
                        .Caption = "Edit Element"
                        .Tag = "Edit"
                        .Picture = pic       'Object of type IPictureDisp
                        .OnAction = "editMag"
                    End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I check in the Watches and it add the control but when I use right-click on a shape the options doesn't appear. Maybe I am not putting where it have to be but I cannot find anywhere an explanation about where is the correct place to set the new element.

Comment: +1 for a good question. MS disabled the ability to edit context menus (a/k/a right-click menus) for some Office components. It may be the case that they do not allow you to manipulate this context menu. I am not able to confirm right now, but I did want to mention that as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

David's correct re 2007, but it seems they've added the ability to customize context menus back in PPT 2010:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/c1eb22ba-6ca8-4c21-8100-62185355aa53/customize-rightclick-context-menu-in-powerpoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

OK I have confirmed that there is:

> Limited support for shortcut menu customizations in PPT 2007+
>   specifically. ....You cannot add any item to the shapes shortcut menu
>   (unless it is an activex control) in PPT 2007+.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/customizing-right-click-menu/76aff9b3-9253-40cf-bd21-e1f832144ad8

You *may* be able to do this with Ribbon/XML interface, but again it may be subject to the annoying limitation that they put on certain context menus. It might simply not be possible to do what you want to do in this version of PowerPoint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469862.aspx#odc_xl_ta_CustomExcelContextMenus_AddDynamicMenu